# One Git command to retrieve all deleted files not staged and committed

Tags: git

In a `git` repository, I have deleted a number of **tracked** files (100+) by mistake.

These deletions have not been staged and committed yet.

Here is what I see when I do `git status`. The number of deleted files is 100+, so I can't retrieve each individually.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

  deleted:    some_tracked_file1.php
  deleted:    some_tracked_file2.php
  deleted:    some_tracked_file3.php
```

How can I undo these changes and thus retrieve all the deleted files with a single command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is right there in the output you quote:

> (use "git checkout -- file..." to discard changes in working directory)

This will discard changes including deletions.

If these are the *only* changes listed, and you want to get rid of *all* of them, then you can do:

```
git reset --hard
```

This will put your working directory back into the state it was at your last commit, discarding any local or staged changes.

If you have other changes that you *don't* want to revert, you'll have to use the `checkout --` command. You can easily script this though, to restore only *deleted but not staged* files on *nix:

```
git status --porcelain | grep -E '^ D' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git checkout --
```

I don't know what an equivalent for Windows might look like, and you'll have issues if you have file names that contain spaces.

Comment: No need to `git reset HEAD *`?

Comment: Only if the changes are staged. You originally said they were, but the quoted output above says they aren't

Comment: So I have just tried `git checkout -- *` and nothing happens

Comment: * will be interpretted by the shell to match local files, which don't exist in this case. Hang on, I'm going to add more to my answer

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: git reset --hard : now you have a powerful command to fix your problem and occasionally cause you more :)

Comment: `git reset --hard` will remove any uncommitted changes. Is there a command that targets deleted files.

Answer (score -2):

if
`git reset --hard` doesn't work, you can use `git revert HEAD` to revert to the last commit (if your files are in the last commit).

Comment: This would be specifically for if you had _committed_ a change deleting the files. Even then, you probably wouldn't want to do this unless you'd made that change public (pushed it to a remote repo, for example)